How to shrink a line and letters in TeX
Please ignore this, if you think it is annoying... it is just about understanding TeX.
In this example, I have two paragraphs of the same text, the first is set with normalfont, the second is set with \bf.
How, if possible at all, may I stretch the first paragraph, and shrink the second, to get the same linebreaks, (at Ut, Beatus, Non est), but keep the impression and balance between normalfont and boldfont without changing fonts?
Please, do not discuss if this makes sense. It is just an experiment.
(And yes, I tried to find out by myself, but didn't understand a thing  .-)).
    \parindent=0pt
\input plipsum
\vsize=22.60cm %8.90in * 2.54 = 22,60cm
\hsize=16.51cm %6,50in * 2.54 = 16.51cm
\lipsum{1}
\vsize=8.90in %22.60cm/2.54 = 8.90in
\hsize=7.23in  %value increased, normal is 16.51/2.54 = 6.50in
{\bf\lipsum{1}}
\bye

If it works, hsizes should be equal.

It would be easier using \sloppy.

\bf doesn't just change the weight. it also changes the width. that is, it alters the font to bold extended. there is no way of doing it which with those fonts which will not result in deformed output. (and if you are happy with the deformation, you can just put it in a box and resize it.) otherwise, you could possibly figure out the closest optical size to a target size defined by font A and then scale font B in that size. however, this would rely on uniform font dimensions, glyph widths and kerning pairs, at least some of which are false of computer modern.

in latex, this is why the default bold used to be (and in some cases still is) bx rather than b. because both computer and latin modern have bold extended fonts, but not (or not many) bold in regular width.

the easiest way to do it is probably to stick to the regular font and typeset the second paragraph twice, displacing the characters slightly the second time to give the 'impression' of bold i.e. poor person's bold or fake bold. you could look at how font installation/selection programmes do it.

@cfr
Thanks, cfr, but, as you know,  I am not looking for the easiest way :-) .  If you like, follow the discussion.

You say what you want is to “stretch or shrink letters and / or lines”. But (1) stretching/shrinking letters is the same as changing fonts, which also you say you don't want to. And (2) stretching/shrinking the lines is the same as changing \hsize, which also you say you don't want to. So it's not clear what you want.

@ShreevatsaR Stretching of letters ist not changing fonts, it is an way to manipulate the current font. It is in fact not easy, to make oneself understood. If I ask, how to get smaller peas, I do not want to get smaller beans.

@MBE Interesting thought. A font is a collection of shapes of letters, and you want to change the shapes of letters. If you stretch the letters in one font, you get another font. Knuth's article The Concept of a Meta-Font is interesting reading. Anyway you have three fonts here (cmr10, cmb10, cmbx10) where "Computer Modern Bold Extended" is indeed a stretched version of "Computer Modern Bold", and treated as a different font, and you can choose between them.

If the bold font has the same metric, then you can keep the same break points. This is typically not true. If the bold font has only scaled metric in x axis, then you can resize \hsize with the same coefficient and you get the same breakpoints. This is true for Computer/Latin Modern normal and bold extended font. The scale parameter is 1.15.
    \parindent=0pt
\input plipsum
\vsize=8.9in %8.90in * 2.54 = 22,60cm
\hsize=5in %6,50in * 2.54 = 16.51cm

Normal font

\lipsum{1}

\medskip
Bold extended font:

{\hsize=1.15\hsize \bf \lipsum{1}}

\bye


+1 nice observation that cmbx metrics are uniformly scaled from cmr.

@wipet As usual, my questions are not so clear as they should be.  In fact, I do not want to shrink the whole paragraph as a unit, like \hbox \vbox or \picture etc, I want to know, how to manipulate the letter and the line itself. Shrinking the boxes would be a kind of manipulating graphics, I want to manipulate the letter itself, without designing a font.. (Even if it sounds nuts.) Basically: If I want to have a "B" smaller and thinner in a given font, is there a way, to do this for all the "B"s in just one document, without diving into font-design??

@wipet I would like to give an example: If I write a text by handwriting, I do adjust the single letter, word and line by a kind of "tension" and individual experience. TeX does not, reasonably. It is a program. In a way, I want to break in the trend, not, to fight against standards, but to understand the basics and to reach the borders of individuality. I really do like the conventions of TeX, but conventions are both: The raise and death of individuality. This is my struggle with those programs: They are doing good, as long as they are not used to subdue.

This is IMHO completely different question. You want to create a macro \mylines with usage \mylines{first line\\second line\\\bf third line.} and you want to have all lines with the same width \hsize. The line breaks are set manually here. It means that not only space deformation should be in progress but letters deformation too in order to reach the given width.  The result will look hideous, it has nothing to do with typography. If this is true, open a different thread and specify more explicitly, what do you want.

@wipet
No, it is ok, as it is.

@wipet TeX is a wonderful compromise between typography and individuality. No doubt about that. The whole thing is about "Do, what you like to do" against "do, as requested".  CTAN is full of individual solutions and for me, this is the fun of it: Everyone might do, as he wants to do, without restrictions and, thanks to Knuth, there seems to be no limit. This is the fascinating point for me: D.E.Knuth designed the program, to get, what he wanted. This is, for me, one of the best manners in TeX and TexExchange: Not to critisize the aim, but to help to reach it. The glue in TeX is tolerance.

@wipet I think, a lot of users missunderstood and are misunderstanding TeX. TeX is not about standardisation , it is about replication and repetition. To me, it seems to be the false aim, to make every document look like any other.  In my opinion, typography is not standardisation, it is the art of being consistent in one work.

Although you asked not to change fonts I only half followed that, I didn't change the first, however the way to achieve your stated aim is to use the bold rather than bold extended font (\cmb10 rather than cmbx10), so that the characters have the same width and line breaking is naturally the same.

\font\tenbf=cmb10
\parindent=0pt
\input plipsum
\vsize=22.60cm %8.90in * 2.54 = 22,60cm
\hsize=16.51cm %6,50in * 2.54 = 16.51cm
\lipsum{1}

{\bf\lipsum{1}}
\bye


At first sight, you are right: Adapting fonts is the art of font designers and a wise user would use these fonts.  I am not wise, but forward.  So let me straighten it out: How may I, without the help of a font- designer, stretch or shrink letters and / or lines, to reach the stated aim?

@MBE see wipet's answer. That is far closer to what you asked. It's fine if you accept that, I would say my answer is closer to what you should do, but accepting another answer is perfectly OK.
